# How do I get the table view to not save notes when there is no text in the text view?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

Im making a notes app and Im trying to figure out how to not save a note in the tableview when there is no text. Right now when I press the save button and theres no text in the text view it still saves it in the table view with a blank cell. Can someone help me with this problem? Thank you! Here is the code Im using when I want to save a note to a table view.

```
    @IBAction func saveNotes(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("SAVE ME")

    var userDefaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    var itemList: NSMutableArray? = userDefaults.objectForKey("itemList") as? NSMutableArray


    var dataSet: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
    dataSet.setObject(textView.text, forKey: "text")

    if ((itemList) != nil) {


        var newMutableList: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

        for dict: AnyObject in itemList! {

            newMutableList.addObject(dict as! NSDictionary)
        }


        userDefaults.removeObjectForKey("itemList")

        newMutableList.addObject(dataSet)
        userDefaults.setObject(newMutableList, forKey: "itemList")





    } else {
        userDefaults.removeObjectForKey("itemList")
        itemList = NSMutableArray()
        itemList!.addObject(dataSet)

        userDefaults.setObject(itemList, forKey: "itemList")


    }

    userDefaults.synchronize()
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)

    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
    self.navigationController?.toolbarHidden = false



}
```

Comment: FYI - do not use `NSUserDefaults` to save data.

Comment: What do you suggest, core data?

Comment: Core data is one of several options. But `NSUserDefaults` is not for data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the string length before you add it in your `dataSet` which I believe is used to render cells in your table view. Something like this:

```
let characterCount = textView.text.characters.count // This is for Swift 2. For Swift use count(textView.text)

if characterCount > 0 {
    dataSet.setObject(textView.text, forKey: "text")
}
```

**EDIT:** Post OP comments

As I suggested, you should disable your save button until there is some text in your text view. This is how you need to do this:

**Step 1:** Set your view controller delegate of your text view.

```
self.textView.delgate = self
```

**Step 2:** Implement following function to enable/disable save button.

```
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
  self.button.enabled = (textView.text.characters.count > 0)
  return true
}
```

PS: As a side note, you may want to safeguard your self from user typing spaces. I am not adding that code here trusting you might already know.

Comment: Should I put this in the viewDidLoad?

Comment: Nope, it should go in your `saveNotes` function because thats the place where you add your text view's text in data model. I would, personally, disable the save button until there is no text in text view so no chance for user to save empty strings.

Comment: It still saves when there is no text.

Comment: Please show your table view data source methods - `numberOfRowsAtIndexPath` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. And did you consider my suggestion of disabling `Save` button until there is no text in text view. Enable it only when something is typed in.

Comment: Yes Im going to use that but the button stays disabled even when there is text in the text view. This is the code I used:           if textView.text.characters.count > 0 {
            button.enabled = true
        } else {
            button.enabled = false
        }

Comment: okay so the button is disabled but when I start typing it doesnt become enabled.

Comment: Ok, use the method `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` instead and it must work. Take a look at my updated post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92622/discussion-between-coding22-and-abhinav).

Answer (score 0):

You need to check textView text length before adding text to your table vie w data source `dataSet`. So give an text length checking condition and avoid doing other task. As like as

```
if textView.text.characters.count > 0 {
     dataSet.setObject(textView.text, forKey: "text")
     // do rest of work
} else
{
     // show an alert for empty text
}
```

Comment: I just tried this and it still saves it when there is no text in the textview.